# How to specify that I want a Set instead of a List in Modello?

Tags: java, modello

I have the following snippet of configuration from a Modello `.mdo` file.

```
<field>
   <name>archetypes</name>
   <association>
     <type>Archetype</type>
     <multiplicity>*</multiplicity>
   </association>
   <description>List of Archetypes available in this catalog.</description>
</field>
```

This generates the following hideous code:

```
/**
 * Field archetypes.
 */
private java.util.List<Archetype> archetypes;
```

and further down:

```
/**
 * Method getArchetypes.
 * 
 * @return List
 */
public java.util.List<Archetype> getArchetypes()
{
    if ( this.archetypes == null )
    {
        this.archetypes = new java.util.ArrayList<Archetype>();
    }

    return this.archetypes;
} //-- java.util.List<Archetype> getArchetypes()
```

How do I tell Modello to use `java.util.Set` instead of `java.util.List` and `java.util.HashSet` instead of `java.util.ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a `<type/>` element on `<field/>` that you can set to `Set`, even though the documentation only mentions native types here.

```
<field>
   <type>Set</type>
   <name>archetypes</name>
   <association>
     <type>Archetype</type>
     <multiplicity>*</multiplicity>
   </association>
   <description>List of Archetypes available in this catalog.</description>
</field>
```

and you control what `Set` implementation with a `<default/>` element, it uses `java.util.HashSet` by default.

```
<default>
    <key>java.util.Set</key>
    <value>new java.util.TreeSet&lt;?&gt;()</value>
</default>
```

Of course, that sets the default for **all** the `Set` types in the class, but I digress, I know enough about Modello to know I don't want to know anymore.

Comment: Does this generate the field of type Set<Archtype>?

Comment: yes, and it uses `HashSet<Archetype>` as the implemenation class, which can be over-ridden with a `<default/>` element to make it use `TreeSet` which is what I needed. I would never use this Modello stuff in a project I was in charge of, it is more levels of indirection for code that could have been easily written and been done with.